# How do I put a listing of files into a menu?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, menuitem

I have a folder with .txt files in it. How can i make my menuitem get those .txt files and put the filenames in the menuitem, so that it creates a list of all .txt files in that folder.

So when i put a .txt in the folder the program automatically creates the menu item.

Does someone knows how to do this, or perhaps an example?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using ASP.Net, you're looking for the [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) and [`Directory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) classes.

Basically, you need to call `Directory.GetFiles` and loop through the results creating MenuItems.
Then, handle the `FileSystemWatcher` events and either rebuild the menu from scratch (simpler) or update the appropriate item (faster)

Comment: @PandaNL, this is actually a good assignment for you to learn how to using WinForms and handling events. There are plenty of FileSystemWatcher examples and MenuItem examples. I do suggest that you use the newer MenuStrip.

Comment: Exactly.  If you cannot figure out how to do this using the `FileSystemWatcher` and `Directory` classes, you should take a basic programming course.